# How can I copy a UnicodeString to a wchar_t array in a C++Builder Android app?

Tags: android, unicode-string, c++builder-10.3-rio

I am using C++Builder 10.3 Rio developing a multi-platform app for Android.

I have an array of data as follows:

```
typedef struct recordstruct
{
    bool shop;
    bool bought;
    wchar_t description[80];
} recordtype;

recordtype MasterItems[MAXITEMS]=
{
    false,false,L"Apples",
    false,false,L"Apricots",
    false,false,L"Avocado",
...
...
};
```

I've copied this into a `TEdit`, and want to get the value back to the `MasterItems` array.

I used to use `c_str()` and `mbstowcs()` and `strcpy()`/`wcscpy()` etc.

How can I do this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnicodeString` is a UTF-16 encoded string on all platforms.  However, `wchar_t` is a 16bit type used for UTF-16 data only on Windows.  On other platforms, `wchar_t` is a 32bit type used for UTF-32 data.

This is documented in Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[String Literals char16_t and wchar_t on macOS and iOS](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Considerations_for_Multi-Device_Applications#String_Literals_char16_t_and_wchar_t_on_macOS_and_iOS)
(Android is included, too)

> On macOS and iOS, `char16_t` is not equivalent to `wchar_t` (as it is on Windows):
>
> - On Windows, `wchar_t` and `char16_t` are both double-byte characters.
> - On `macOS`, `iOS`, **and Android**, however, a `wchar_t` is a 4-byte character.
>
> So, to declare UTF-16 constant strings, on Windows use either the `L` or the `u` prefix, whereas on macOS, iOS, **and Android**, use the `u` prefix.
>
> Example on Windows:
>
> `UnicodeString(L"Text"), UnicodeString(u"Text")`
>
> Example on macOS, iOS, **and Android**:
>
> `UnicodeString(u"Text")`
>
> Using the `L` prefix for string literals on macOS, iOS, **and Android** is not, however, wrong. In this case, UTF-32 constant strings are converted to UTF-16 strings.
>
> For portability, use the `_D` macro to write constant strings that are prefixed accordingly with `L` or `u`. Example:
>
> `UnicodeString(_D("Text"))`

To ensure UTF-16 is used on all platforms, the `System::WideChar` type is an alias for `wchar_t` on Windows and `char16_t` on other platforms.  `UnicodeString` is a container of `WideChar` elements.

So, if you use `wchar_t` for your array, then on non-Windows platforms you will need to first convert your `UnicodeString` to UTF-32 at runtime, such as with the RTL's [`UnicodeStringToUCS4String()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeStringToUCS4String) function, before you can then copy that data into your array, eg:

```cpp
typedef struct recordstruct
{
    bool shop;
    bool bought;
    wchar_t description[80];
} recordtype;

recordtype MasterItems[MAXITEMS]=
{
    false,false,L"Apples",
    false,false,L"Apricots",
    false,false,L"Avocado",
    ...
};

...

#if defined(WIDECHAR_IS_WCHAR) // WideChar = wchar_t = 2 bytes

StrLCopy(MasterItems[index].description, Edit1->Text.c_str(), std::size(MasterItems[index].description)-1); // -1 for null terminator

/* or:
UnicodeString s = Edit1->Text;
size_t len = std::min(s.Length(), std::size(MasterItems[index].destination)-1); // -1 for null terminator
std::copy_n(s.c_str(), len, MasterItems[index].destination);
MasterItems[index].destination[len] = L'\0';
*/

#elif defined(WIDECHAR_IS_CHAR16) // WideChar = char16_t, wchar_t = 4 bytes

UCS4String s = UnicodeStringToUCS4String(Edit1->Text);
size_t len = std::min(s.Length-1, std::size(MasterItems[index].destination)-1); // UCS4String::Length includes the null terminator!
std::copy_n(&s[0], len, MasterItems[index].destination);
MasterItems[index].destination[len] = L'\0';

#else

// unsupported wchar_t size!

#endif
```

Otherwise, if you want to ensure your array is always 16bit UTF-16 on all platforms, then you need to use `char16_t` or `WideChar` instead of `wchar_t` in your array.  The `u` prefix creates a `char16_t`-based literal, and the RTL's `_D()` macro creates a `WideChar`-based literal (using `L` or `u` according to platform), eg:

```cpp
typedef struct recordstruct
{
    bool shop;
    bool bought;
    char16_t description[80]; // or: System::WideChar
} recordtype;

recordtype MasterItems[MAXITEMS]=
{
    false,false,u"Apples", // or: _D("Apples")
    false,false,u"Apricots", // or: _D("Apricots")
    false,false,u"Avocado", // or: _D("Avocado")
    ...
};

...

StrLCopy(MasterItems[index].description, Edit1->Text.c_str(), std::size(MasterItems[index].description)-1); // -1 for null terminator

/* or:
UnicodeString s = Edit1->Text;
size_t len = std::min(s.Length(), std::size(MasterItems[index].description)-1); // -1 for null terminator
std::copy_n(s.c_str(), len, MasterItems[index].description);
MasterItems[index].description[len] = u'\0'; // or: _D('\0')
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, Remy, you've saved me again !